# How to fetch data into Victory Native Charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, victory-charts, victory-native

I am using victory native chart to render area chart and i dont know how to fetch data from api to the chart, meaning x will hold "usia" and y will hold "indeks_massa". anyone good people can help me to solve this? :(

this is my code:

```
const data = listHistory.map((usia, indeks_massa) => {
    return { x: usia, y: indeks_massa }
})
<VictoryLine style={{ data: { stroke: "blue" }, }}
             data={data}
/>
```

Comment: Are you actually _getting_ data from the API but don't know how to add it to the chart (in which case can you add a sample of that data to your question), or are you stuck on getting data from the API in the first place?

Comment: actually i have get the data from API and put the data in state [listHistory, setListHistory] but i dont know how to add it to the chart

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'll need to get the data, set state with it, and update the component with some additional information - at least based [on their documentation](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs). If you need to manipulate the data you can do that before you add it to state.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

// Transforms the data
function mappedData(data) {
  return data.map((el, index) => {
    return { x: el, y: index };
  });
}

function Example() {

  const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);

  // Run `getData` once (the empty dependency array
  // `[]` ensures that). `getData` fetches the JSON,
  // and parses it, and then `setData` adds the (now
  // transformed data to state.
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const response = await fetch(<endpoint>);
      const data = await response.json();
      setData(mappedData(data));
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <VictoryBar
      data={data}
      x="x"
      y="x"
    />
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While implementing the **'Vectory Native'** chart, a limitation I encountered was its support solely for data in the key-value format, such as [{key:1,value:12}, {key:2,value:22}, {key:3,value:32}]. However, in real-time applications, data often arrives in the form of an array of objects, like [{key:[1,2,3], value:[12,22,32]}].

To make this compatible, data manipulation using 'map' becomes necessary. Unfortunately, with large datasets, this can lead to **performance issues** due to the computational overhead involved in restructuring the data format.

In such cases, exploring optimization techniques or alternative chart libraries that handle object array data more efficiently could be beneficial. Some options might include pre-processing the data before feeding it into the charting library or utilizing libraries specifically designed for handling complex data structures efficiently in visualization tools.